# building a calendar using javascript where you can add and modify events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to build a calendar with javasCript that allow users to enter their shift manually and have 2 option when a date is clicked on( swap or give away)? any thought on how to do it? im I going to need an API? building the calendar will I have to build it using table or which is most efficient way?
I am a rookie coder who started less than a month so pardon if I am not too specific.

Answer (score 1):

How about a php calendar? This works good http://fast-apps.co.uk/fast_cal.php#go

Also you can use Google Calendar and embed that too. 
[Here is an example](http://www.ahepadistrict9.org/calendar.html) of where I have it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP yet and I want stick with JavaScript till I get it before moving on. I hope that's a good thing. Thanks for your help